# How to convert complex lists into strings and back in Python 3.7?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.7

I'm trying to save Python lists to a file and read them back again when I re-launch the program. The problem is my lists are complex: i.e. different amounts of tuples within tuples.

The best I could come up with is turning my list into a string initially (which works) but there's no way I can think of to revert the changes.

```
with open(filename, 'w') as f:
            f.write(str(objs))
            f.close()
```

This works but how do I return this to a list?

Just to clarify what my definition of a complex list is, here's an example:

```
[(((0.0, 0.0, 0.0), (1000.0, 0.0, 0.0), (0.0, 2.0, 0.0), (1000.0, 2.0, 
0.0), (0.0, 0.0, 1000.0), (1000.0, 0.0, 1000.0), (0.0, 2.0, 1000.0), 
(1000.0, 2.0, 1000.0)), ((0, 2, 3, 1), (4, 6, 7, 5), (1, 3, 7, 5), (4, 6, 
2, 0), (2, 6, 7, 3), (4, 0, 1, 5)), ((255, 0, 0), (255, 128, 0), (255, 255, 
0), (255, 255, 255), (0, 0, 255), (0, 255, 0)))]
```

Comment: You could save the list in a [pickle](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html) file, or save it as [json](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) (though this will convert the tuples to lists).

Comment: "The best I could come up with is turning my list into a string initially" don't do that. Use a supported serialization format, like `pickle` for arbitrary objects, or even just `json` will work for a simple list

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @snakecharmerb already mentioned you can use `json` or `pickle`. Here is an example:

Code:

```
my_list = [(((0.0, 0.0, 0.0), (1000.0, 0.0, 0.0), (0.0, 2.0, 0.0), (1000.0, 2.0, 
0.0), (0.0, 0.0, 1000.0), (1000.0, 0.0, 1000.0), (0.0, 2.0, 1000.0), 
(1000.0, 2.0, 1000.0)), ((0, 2, 3, 1), (4, 6, 7, 5), (1, 3, 7, 5), (4, 6, 
2, 0), (2, 6, 7, 3), (4, 0, 1, 5)), ((255, 0, 0), (255, 128, 0), (255, 255, 
0), (255, 255, 255), (0, 0, 255), (0, 255, 0)))]
```

---

```
import json

with open('my_list.json', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(my_list, f)

with open('my_list.json','r') as f:
    loaded_list = json.load(f)

print('Using json:')
print(loaded_list)
```

---

```
import pickle

with open('my_list.pkl', 'wb') as f:
    pickle.dump(my_list, f)

with open('my_list.pkl', 'rb') as f:
    loaded_list = pickle.load(f)

print('Using pickle:')
print(loaded_list)
```

---

Output:

```
Using json:
[[[[0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [1000.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 2.0, 0.0], [1000.0, 2.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 1000.0], [1000.0, 0.0, 1000.0], [0.0, 2.0, 1000.0], [1000.0, 2.0, 1000.0]], [[0, 2, 3, 1], [4, 6, 7, 5], [1, 3, 7, 5], [4, 6, 2, 0], [2, 6, 7, 3], [4, 0, 1, 5]], [[255, 0, 0], [255, 128, 0], [255, 255, 0], [255, 255, 255], [0, 0, 255], [0, 255, 0]]]]

Using pickle:
[(((0.0, 0.0, 0.0), (1000.0, 0.0, 0.0), (0.0, 2.0, 0.0), (1000.0, 2.0, 0.0), (0.0, 0.0, 1000.0), (1000.0, 0.0, 1000.0), (0.0, 2.0, 1000.0), (1000.0, 2.0, 1000.0)), ((0, 2, 3, 1), (4, 6, 7, 5), (1, 3, 7, 5), (4, 6, 2, 0), (2, 6, 7, 3), (4, 0, 1, 5)), ((255, 0, 0), (255, 128, 0), (255, 255, 0), (255, 255, 255), (0, 0, 255), (0, 255, 0)))]
```

As you can see `json` converts tuples to lists.

Comment: Yes, this is spot on. So, instead of initially converting your list to string and writing to a file, you can save this in a pickle file. fileName = "my_list"
fileObject = open(fileName,'wb')
pickle.dump(my_list,fileObject)   
fileObject.close()

Comment: You could use cpickle instead of pickle, cpickle is optimized and much-much faster than pickle especially if the size of data is large. the above code can be changed like "import cpickle as pickle"

Answer (score 1):

`str` function will convert your complex list / nested lists and tuple to string
Further, `eval` converts any string to an actual code snippet

However as mentioned by Taras Savchyn, `eval` can lead to SQL injections and more. So instead use `ast.literal_eval`

Hence:

```py
>>>import ast

>>> mylist = [(((0.0, 0.0, 0.0), (1000.0, 0.0, 0.0), (0.0, 2.0, 0.0), (1000.0, 2.0, 0.0), (0.0, 0.0, 1000.0), (1000.0, 0.0, 1000.0), (0.0, 2.0, 1000.0), (1000.0, 2.0, 1000.0)), ((0, 2, 3, 1), (4, 6, 7, 5), (1, 3, 7, 5), (4, 6, 2, 0), (2, 6, 7, 3), (4, 0, 1, 5)), ((255, 0, 0), (255, 128, 0), (255, 255, 0), (255, 255, 255), (0, 0, 255), (0, 255, 0)))]

>>> mylist
[(((0.0, 0.0, 0.0), (1000.0, 0.0, 0.0), (0.0, 2.0, 0.0), (1000.0, 2.0, 0.0), (0.0, 0.0, 1000.0), (1000.0, 0.0, 1000.0), (0.0, 2.0, 1000.0), (1000.0, 2.0, 1000.0)), ((0, 2, 3, 1), (4, 6, 7, 5), (1, 3, 7, 5), (4, 6, 2, 0), (2, 6, 7, 3), (4, 0, 1, 5)), ((255, 0, 0), (255, 128, 0), (255, 255, 0), (255, 255, 255), (0, 0, 255), (0, 255, 0)))]

>>> mystring = str(mylist)

>>> print(mystring)
'[(((0.0, 0.0, 0.0), (1000.0, 0.0, 0.0), (0.0, 2.0, 0.0), (1000.0, 2.0, 0.0), (0.0, 0.0, 1000.0), (1000.0, 0.0, 1000.0), (0.0, 2.0, 1000.0), (1000.0, 2.0, 1000.0)), ((0, 2, 3, 1), (4, 6, 7, 5), (1, 3, 7, 5), (4, 6, 2, 0), (2, 6, 7, 3), (4, 0, 1, 5)), ((255, 0, 0), (255, 128, 0), (255, 255, 0), (255, 255, 255), (0, 0, 255), (0, 255, 0)))]'

>>> type(mystring)
<class 'str'>

>>> print(ast.literal_eval(mystring))
[(((0.0, 0.0, 0.0), (1000.0, 0.0, 0.0), (0.0, 2.0, 0.0), (1000.0, 2.0, 0.0), (0.0, 0.0, 1000.0), (1000.0, 0.0, 1000.0), (0.0, 2.0, 1000.0), (1000.0, 2.0, 1000.0)), ((0, 2, 3, 1), (4, 6, 7, 5), (1, 3, 7, 5), (4, 6, 2, 0), (2, 6, 7, 3), (4, 0, 1, 5)), ((255, 0, 0), (255, 128, 0), (255, 255, 0), (255, 255, 255), (0, 0, 255), (0, 255, 0)))]

>>> type(ast.literal_eval(mystring))
<class 'list'>
```

Hope this solves your problem. You can comment the answer to ask any further queries

Comment: Using eval is a bad practice. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832940/why-is-using-eval-a-bad-practice